# Merged my two accounts on SO, but I lost my flag-weight

Tags: support, flag-weight

I recently (by accident, actually) merged my 2 accounts on SO, one of which had a flag weight that was well over 300 (if I recall correctly). However, this did not transfer over when the accounts were merged, likely due to the fact that it was the new account with the weight.

Is there anything that can be done to correct this?

Comment: Why did you have two accounts?

Comment: Flag weight is so inconsequential.  Please pay attention to your rep instead.

Comment: Reputation is so inconsequential. Please pay attention to your badges instead.

Comment: Badges are so inconsequential. Please pay attention to your family instead.

Comment: @MatthewRead Accident, I use 2 different emails regularly.

Comment: OK, upvotered :)

Comment: Same thing happened to me after adding a login to one account that was associated with an account I'd created, forgotten and never used. The active account had a weight of more than 500. Now it's zero.

Comment: General note for those closing as off topic: account merge can occur on any site, not just Stack Overflow. The fact this question is old and was written when Meta acted as the per-site meta of SO does not mean we should close all those questions now.